# Format dataframe with no spaces and bold

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I have no idea how to go about this.  I'd like to print the dataframe df1 with no spaces between the numbers, after formatting them using df2 such that the corresponding values in df1 are bolded:

```
df1 = t(data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)))
df2 = t(data.frame(c(F,F,T),c(T,T,F)))
```

desired output:

> 12**3**
>
> **12**3

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021090/color-and-style-format-data-frames-in-r) might be of help

Comment: Easiest answer is probably "Do it in Excel."